# js canvas нарисовать спецсимволы

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

нужно вывести на canvas спецсимвол альфа (α)

`ctx.fillText("&alpha;",50,195);`

выводит такой же текст `&alpha;`

как нарисовать спецсимвол?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете использовать прям символы для вставки значений:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);
        ctx.clearRect(45,45,60,60);
        ctx.strokeRect(50,50,50,50);
        ctx.fillText("α®™¾Ω;",55,75);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">

</canvas>
```